# How do I show that this function is nonnegative?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, fourier-analysis

Let $\lambda$ be a Borel probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\phi$ be its characteristic function (that is, $\phi(u)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{i \langle u,x \rangle} d\lambda(x)$), and assume that $\phi\in L^1(m)$.

Define $f(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \phi(u)e^{-i \langle u,x \rangle} dm(u)$.

How do I show that $f$ is nonnegative “everywhere”?

(The only thing I can derive now is that $f$ is real and continuous and bounded)

Comment: What is the proof in case $n=1$?

Comment: There is no difference for the case $n=1$. Most textbooks first show that $f$ is bounded and continuous and then show that $\int_{(a_1,b_1]\times \cdots \times (a_n,b_n]}fdm = \lambda((a_1,b_1]\times\cdots \times (a_n,b_n])$ for all some “good” rectangles, using Fourier inversion. Then, conclude that $f$ is a p.d.f. of $\lambda$. Hence $f$ is $m$-a.e. nonnegative, and since $f$ is continuous, it is everywhere nonnegative.

Comment: However, I am asking this question since I am not clear for the part concluding $f$ is a p.d.f. of $\lambda$. Since we don’t know $f$ is whether nonnwgative or not at that step, I think we can not simply conclude that $f$ is a p.d.f. of $\lambda$, because we don’t know if $f$ is $L^1$.

Comment: Perhaps you could add these explanations to your question... this would make your question much clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that there exists $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(x)<0$. As $f$ is continuous, we can find a "good" rectangle $I$ and some $\epsilon>0$ such that $x \in I$ and

$$f(y) \leq -\epsilon <0 \qquad \text{for all $y \in I$}.$$

This would imply

$$\int_I f \, dm \leq - \epsilon m(I) <0$$

in contradiction to

$$\int_I f \, dm = \lambda(I) \geq 0.$$

Consequently we conclude that $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. By choosing a sequence of "good" rectangles $I_k \uparrow \mathbb{R}^n$, we find from the monotone convergence theorem that

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f\, dm = \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \int_{I_k} f \, dm = \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \lambda(I_k) \leq 1,$$

and so $f \in L^1(m)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I don’t get why most textbooks do not point out this..

Comment: @Rubertos You are welcome.